# Compare row values of same table to particular condition

Tags: sql-server, join, nested-loops

**Screenshot of database :**
[image]

I want to display data in SQL by comparing username of users who are not admin(is_admin = true) to the user who is admin. I only want to display data, where anno_type, capture_end, capture_start and severity doesn't match with admins value. for eg. if non admins have some data with noisy(anno_type) with minimal(severity) from 1(capture_start) to 3401(capture_end) but admin has marked it noisy with min from 1 to 3401 and noisy with moderate from 3401 to 6401, then the query should display noisy moderate from 3401 to 6401

Its been 7 years since I have handled such complex(for me) sql queries. I remember only bits and pieces of SQL.
I remember joins but cant figure it out how to apply here

I am having some success with this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE capture_end IN
    (SELECT capture_end
     FROM test
     WHERE username = 'P' AND drive_session_name = '046_156')
  AND capture_start IN
    (SELECT capture_start
     FROM test
     WHERE username = 'P' AND drive_session_name = '046_156')
  AND anno_type NOT IN
    (SELECT anno_type
     FROM test
     WHERE username = 'P' AND drive_session_name = '046_156')
  AND severity IN
    (SELECT severity
     FROM test
     WHERE username = 'P' AND drive_session_name = '046_156')
  AND drive_session_name = '046_156'
  AND username != 'P'
```

This doesn't show data if severity of same annotation is different for admins and non admins

Answer (score 0):

You can `EXIST` to obtain the same results. `EXISTS` is a semi-join and provide good performance for properly indexed tables.

Here I've used a `cte` to avoid multiple inner select statements

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT capture_end,anno_type,severity
    FROM test
    WHERE username = 'P' AND drive_session_name = '046_156'
)
SELECT *
FROM test t
WHERE drive_session_name = '046_156' AND username != 'P'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE WHERE CTE.capture_end = t.capture_end)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE WHERE CTE.anno_type = t.anno_type)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE WHERE CTE.severity = t.severity)
```

---

**Edit:** The code above is just a better approach to the code you've written.

Since you've asked

> I only want to display data, where anno_type, capture_end,
>   capture_start and severity doesn't match with admins value

You could try something as simple as an `EXCEPT`

Example :

```
select capture_start,capture_end,anno_type,severity
from test
where is_admin = 'true' -- <addtional where conditions>
except 
select capture_start,capture_end,anno_type,severity
from test
where is_admin = 'false'  -- <addtional where conditions>
```

will give all the non-matching entry for an admin user. Reverse the table, you have the changes for non-admin users.

I have created a fiddle with minimum data [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cc515f0d6d117c1337bf978191c9a22c)

Comment: this does not give me values which are not in admin and vice versa

Comment: to compare capture start, end, type, severity of non admins to admins, i would require a join, how can i include a join in above statement. i have included test db https://rextester.com/TDAE91242

Comment: @SurajSingh, the query you've written will give exactly those entries where there is a difference in non-admin to admin. Could you please update the expected output also(tabular form) in the question?
note: you don't need a join to compare 2 resultsets